# ActionBar expand when enter text in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I have a fragment with Tabs and ViewPager. In a fragment of the ViewPager I have an EditText and when I try to enter text, the ActionBar is expanded and I can't see the EditText.

[image: Result when try to enter text in EditText]

This is the layout for the fragment with Tabs and ViewPager:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.rey.material.widget.TabPageIndicator
    style="@style/TabPageIndicator"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shadow"/>
```

This is the code for the ToolBar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/ToolBarStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

And this is the ToolBarStyle:

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/toolbar_elevation</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Whan it could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post full code?

Comment: can you add xml contains tollbar code?

Comment: I have added the code for the toolbar and style for toolbar in the question. Thanks

Comment: Can you change toolbar height?android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"

Comment: android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" to your toolbar.

Comment: I delete this line and occur the same, the actionbar is expanded when enter text in edittext.

Comment: I put the android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" and I have the same problem, the actionbar is expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `setFitsSystemWindows` of Toolbar to `false`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.yourToolbar)
toolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
```

Or you can set it in xml using `fitsSystemWindows` at `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable `adjustResize`, add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your activity's parent layout.